# chart.js add label into tooltip

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) for line graphs to show trends over time, but it's not clear when hovering over a data point what it's for.

Is there a way to add the label from the data into the tooltip?

I am currently doing this to add a "%" after the tooltip data, as I'm dealing with percentages like so:

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
      var value = data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index];
      return value + '%';
    }
  },
},
```

So I want it so when they hover over the data point on the lines, it will say "legend - data%".

Here's a full example of the code with the data:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myLineChart');
var myChart = new Chart.Line(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Jul-2016', 'Sep-2016', 'Oct-2016', 'Dec-2016', 'Jan-2017'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Ubuntu-based',
      fill: false,
      data: [
        ["Ubuntu-based", "51.37"],
        ["Ubuntu-based", "51.04"],
        ["Ubuntu-based", "50.64"],
        ["Ubuntu-based", "50.29"],
        ["Ubuntu-based", "49.6"]
      ],
      borderColor: '#a6cee3',
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: 'Arch-based',
      fill: false,
      data: [
        ["Arch-based", "28.52"],
        ["Arch-based", "28.53"],
        ["Arch-based", "28.75"],
        ["Arch-based", "29.02"],
        ["Arch-based", "29.16"]
      ],
      borderColor: '#1f78b4',
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: 'Debian',
      fill: false,
      data: [
        ["Debian", "6.73"],
        ["Debian", "6.74"],
        ["Debian", "6.75"],
        ["Debian", "6.82"],
        ["Debian", "6.79"]
      ],
      borderColor: '#b2df8a',
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: 'Fedora',
      fill: false,
      data: [
        ["Fedora", "3.92"],
        ["Fedora", "4.09"],
        ["Fedora", "4.07"],
        ["Fedora", "4.14"],
        ["Fedora", "4.53"]
      ],
      borderColor: '#33a02c',
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: 'openSUSE',
      fill: false,
      data: [
        ["openSUSE", "3.15"],
        ["openSUSE", "3.05"],
        ["openSUSE", "2.98"],
        ["openSUSE", "3.03"],
        ["openSUSE", "3.02"]
      ],
      borderColor: '#fb9a99',
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: 'Gentoo',
      fill: false,
      data: [
        ["Gentoo", "3.08"],
        ["Gentoo", "2.98"],
        ["Gentoo", "3.04"],
        ["Gentoo", "3.03"],
        ["Gentoo", "2.91"]
      ],
      borderColor: '#e31a1c',
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: 'SteamOS',
      fill: false,
      data: [
        ["SteamOS", "1.26"],
        ["SteamOS", "1.62"],
        ["SteamOS", "1.58"],
        ["SteamOS", "1.57"],
        ["SteamOS", "1.67"]
      ],
      borderColor: '#fdbf6f',
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: 'Slackware',
      fill: false,
      data: [
        ["Slackware", "0.63"],
        ["Slackware", "0.58"],
        ["Slackware", "0.52"],
        ["Slackware", "0.49"],
        ["Slackware", "0.61"]
      ],
      borderColor: '#ff7f00',
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: 'Mageia',
      fill: false,
      data: [
        ["Mageia", "0.63"],
        ["Mageia", "0.65"],
        ["Mageia", "0.61"],
        ["Mageia", "0.58"],
        ["Mageia", "0.59"]
      ],
      borderColor: '#cab2d6',
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: 'Solus',
      fill: false,
      data: [
        ["Solus", "0.42"],
        ["Solus", "0.45"],
        ["Solus", "0.61"],
        ["Solus", "0.64"],
        ["Solus", "0.92"]
      ],
      borderColor: '#6a3d9a',
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: 'Sabayon',
      fill: false,
      data: [
        ["Sabayon", "0.21"],
        ["Sabayon", "0.19"],
        ["Sabayon", "0.24"],
        ["Sabayon", "0.23"],
        ["Sabayon", "0.22"]
      ],
      borderColor: '',
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: 'Chakra',
      fill: false,
      data: [
        ["Chakra", "0.07"],
        ["Chakra", "0.06"],
        ["Chakra", "0.06"],
        ["Chakra", "0.06"],
        ["Chakra", "0.05"]
      ],
      borderColor: '',
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: 'Netrunner',
      fill: false,
      data: [
        ["Netrunner", "0.06"],
        ["Netrunner", "0.06"],
        ["Netrunner", "0.05"]
      ],
      borderColor: '',
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Percentage of users'
        }
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var value = data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index];
          var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
          return label + value + '%';
        }
      },
    },
  }
});
```

So when you hover over a data point in the "Ubuntu-based" data column, the tooltip would have "Ubuntu-based" in it.

EDIT:

The answer was to change the callback to this

```
label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
      var value = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[0];
      var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
      return label + ' ' + value + '%';
}
```

Comment: please provide a working sample code on what you have done. And what kind of "legend" are you expecting on the tooltip?

Comment: Added more code for you.

Comment: If you go here https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/core/core.tooltip.js and go to line 44, that is probably the logic that you're after. But I have not tested this

Comment: Edited the answer I found myself.

Comment: for some other chart types u can achieve this: `chartData.labels[tooltipItem.index]`

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this to work properly and if you want to include all data for a given date:

```
options: {
              tooltips: {
                  mode: 'index',
                  intersect: false,
                  callbacks: {
                      label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                          var value = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                          var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;

                          return label + ': ' + value;
                      }
                  }
              },
          }
```